# Laravel newing up a model

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a difference in Laravel in making a model like

```
App::make('User');
```

and

```
new User();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolving an object out of the container (`App::make('User')`) provides some extra benefits if you have created custom bindings in the container, or you have dependencies in the constructor you'd like automatically resolved.

If neither of those apply, then there is no difference. If you have not specifically setup a custom binding in the container for `'User'`, and there are no required dependencies in the constructor, then `App::make('User')` will just run `new User()`.

I would suggest you check out the [documentation on the service container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container) for more information.